# What is a right way to use task directive in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to multiply two matrices using OpenMP task. This is a basic code:

```
long i, j, k;

   for (i = 0; i < N; i ++)
      for (j = 0; j < N; j ++)
         for (k = 0; k < N; k ++)
            c[i * N + j] += a[i * N + k] * b[k * N + j];
```

So, I want to use task on column level and then I modified code like this:

```
   long i, j, k;
#pragma omp parallel 
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
   for (i = 0; i < N; i ++)
     #pragma omp task private(i, j, k)
     {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j ++)
         for (k = 0; k < N; k ++)

            c[i * N + j] += a[i * N + k] * b[k * N + j];
      }
    }
  }
```

When I run a program I get message like this:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Now, I know I'm missing some piece, but can't figure it what. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`private` variables in OpenMP are not initialised and have random initial values. When the task executes, `i` would have random value and therefore probably lead to an out-of-bound access of `c[]` and `a[]`.

`firstprivate` variables are similar to `private`, but have their initial value set to the value that the referenced variable had at the moment the construct is entered. In your case `i` has to be `firstprivate` and not `private`.

Also it is advisable that `i` is made `private` in the parallel region for a small performance increase. Thus the final code should look like this (with all variable sharing classes written explicitly and private variables declared in their use scopes):

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(a, b, c)
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      long i;
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
         #pragma omp task shared(a, b, c) firstprivate(i)
         {
            int j, k;
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
               for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                  c[i * N + j] += a[i * N + k] * b[k * N + j];
         }
   }
}
```